# getting the current indexPath of UITableview in another Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, viewcontroller

I have a `UITableView` , when each cell is clicked , it loads the details page, where the name and subtitle is loaded from tableview cell name and subtitle.

I have done the following to do this

1. declared a `var` Row of type `Int` and in didSelectRowAt method, `indexPath` is passed to this variable

2.Destination has another variable rownum  and  this is assigned as

```
`destination1.rownum = row`
```

in the
`prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` Method

My problem is , when I click the 1st cell, value of  rownum = 0
but this remain unchanged and on next cell click , this shows the 0th value itself.

likewise it shows the previous values only

How can I reset this rownum/ row once all this values are loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an extra variable.

- If the origin of the segue is the **cell** then the cell is passed in the `sender` parameter and you get the index path with

  ```
  let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: sender as! UITableViewCell)!
  ```
- If the origin of the segue is the **controller** and you call `performSegue` in `didSelectRow` pass `indexPath` in the `sender` parameter yourself. Then get the index path in `prepare(for` with

  ```
  let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath
  ```

If there is only one segue force unwrapping the values is fine as the segue is *hard-connected*. If there are multiple segues you better safely unwrap the `sender`.

Comment: Thank You!!! it worked. First one was my case. Before  I was trying switch- cases and if else conditions . But this solved in a single line